# How to properly represent a MongooseModel on typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Recently I have crossed by this problem on mongoose types. I do have my mongoose model as expected and I have used interfaces to do the typing for it. The  problem is with the specifica type MongooseMap.

The MongooseMap has properties that the classic Map type from typescrit hasn't. For example:

```
const savedNotification = await Notification.findOne({ _id: notification._id })
savedNotification!.data.toJSON()
```

The toJSON() mehtod isnt part of the Map type so the typescript does not recognize the method. My question is how do I represent the MongooseModel with typescript?

For now I have being using a not so good approach. This is my code for now:

```
import { NotificationType } from "@/types/notification";
import mongoose from "mongoose";


interface NotificationAttrs {
    receivers: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[]
    sender: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    type: NotificationType
    data: Record<string, unknown>
    sentAt: Date
}

interface NotificationModel extends mongoose.Model<NotificationDoc> {
    build(attrs: NotificationAttrs): NotificationDoc
}

interface NotificationDoc extends mongoose.Document {
    receivers: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[]
    sender: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    type: NotificationType
    data: { [key: string]: any } // IDk how to represent the MongooseModel type
    sentAt: Date
}

const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    receivers: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    sender: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true, enum: Object.values(NotificationType) },
    data: { type: Map, of: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true },
    sentAt: { type: Date, required: true },
})
notificationSchema.statics.build = (attrs: NotificationAttrs) => {
    return new Notification(attrs);
}

const Notification = mongoose.model<NotificationDoc, NotificationModel>('Notification', notificationSchema);

export { Notification }
```

As you can see I am only using a generic object, but I don't like this approach since now I can use any property or method name on it and the typescript will not complain about it. Anyone has a better approach for this?

Comment: Good, but I have a question, is possible to use Mongoose Model like a type for example in enum, `enum Models { notification: MotificationModel }`